# Making custom FilterBarView for ListDefinition

Tags: gui-extensions, 2011-sp1

I would like to make my own FilterBarView to go along with some ListDefinitions that I have made.

I have taken a look at DefaultListbar and SearchListbBar in CME/Views/ListFilters but I am unable to get a grasp on how to implement it. When I copy the DefaultListbar aspx to my own page, I just get the view you can see in the image. This will just continue to look like this (no errors in JS console).

[image: Broken FilterBarView]

So I would just like to get some documentation or a good example for how to make my own FilterBarView. Tips are also always welcome.

Answer (score 3):

That would probably worth separate blog post,

But trying to simplify, the steps you need to do are the following:

1. Implement list bar as an instance of `Tridion.Cme.Views.ListFilterView`
2. In your list bar view implement the methods

   - `view.getHeight();`
   - `view.updateView(itemId, params);`
   - `view.getFilter();`

As an examples you can look at `Tridion.Cme.Views.SearchListBarView` or `Tridion.Cme.Views.DefaultListBarView` or possibly `Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.Views.ExternalSearchListBar` (if you have ECL available)

3. In list definitions define reference to listbar `<list:filterbarView url="~/Views/ListFilters/CustomlSearchListBar.aspx"/>`

As for the view which is not working, make sure the `Tridion.Controls.FilteredList.prototype._forwardCallToView` performs correctly, as it seems that List can’t find the View. I can assume the URL you defined has the wrong path and can`t be resolved.

Comment: Sorry that I left open this question as I was able to solve it a while ago (forgot that I put it here).

And indeed I followed those steps but the problem I had with it not loading was the using <list:filterbarView url="~/Views/ListFilters/CustomlSearchListBar.aspx"/> would not work as I defined my Editor in another Virtual Directory. So I had to define <list:filterbarView url="WebUI/Editors/CME/Views/ListFilters/CustomlSearchListBar.aspx"/>